# VBA - XML Mappings are not exporting when using VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, mapping

I am using a macro wrote in VBA to export all my work sheets in my workbook to XML at the same time, but I have created Mappings for the header on the columns but they are not exporting with the sheets.
Only if I go to the Developer tag and export to XML does it work.

Is it possible to export all sheets to XML at the same time with the mappings assigned?

```
Sub Splitziez()

Dim strPath As String
strPath = "C:\Test"
For Each sheetz0r In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    sheetz0r.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileFormat:=xlXMLSpreadsheet, 
Filename:=strPath & "\" & sheetz0r.Name
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strpath As String
    Dim xFile As String

    strpath = "C:\Test"

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Copy
        xFile = strpath & "\" & ws.Name & ".XML"
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xFile
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next



End Sub
```